# C++ access members and functions

Tags: c++

I'm fairly familiar with Java and C# and want to broaden my horizon with C++.

But I am having trouble to understand when to use the `->` or the `.` operator when accessing a member or a method of an objcect.

I'm sure that I'm not the first one to ask this question. There are a lot of questions out there that tackle the same problem, but I just can't relate the provided answers to my special case.

I have a very simple class that is called `Stock`:

```
class Stock
{
public:
    int32_t value;
    string name;

    Stock(void);
    ~Stock(void);

    void doStuff();
};
```

I know that if the object is allocated on the heap I have to use `->` and `.` when it resides in stack space.

But if I wanted to print the length of the name string of a `Stock` object I would need to do something like this:

```
Stock* bmw = new Stock;
bmw->name = "BMw";
cout << bmw->name.length() << endl;
```

The name of the stock is accessed via the "->" operator, the length of the name via the "." operator. 
In my view, both of these objects (the stock and the string) reside in heap space, so i would only need the -> operator, right?

What am I missing here? How is it with strings? I thougt strings are always pointers...
Could you please explain the concepts that are working here a bit?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Markus

Comment: Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/241631). The best way to learn C++ is to start reading a good book.

Comment: if you didn't make `bmw` a pointer, you could access the members with the `.` operator. The `->` operator dereferences and accesses the member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->` is used when you have a *pointer*, `.` is used when you have an *instance*.

In your example, `bmw` is a pointer to a `Stock` instance, so you reference it's members by using the `->` operator.  the `name` field is a string *instance*, so you use the `.` operator.

You could also write it as

```
(*bmw).name = "BMw";
```

Since `*bmw` returns the *instance* whose address is stored in the varialbe `bmw`

It's as simple as that - don't confuse yourself by bringing in the stack and heap.  Those are just memory allocation implementation details.

Comment: ". is used when you have an instance **or a reference**"

Answer (score 1):

Just know that you use the arrow operator (->) when u point to an object.
in your case, the name member is not a pointer to std::string, so you can't use the arrow operator, instead you use the dot (.).

you could do something like this :

```
std::string* name;
Stock* sptr = new Stock;
sptr->name = new std::string("blah blah blah");
std::cout << sptr->name->length << std::endl;
```

Comment: `sptr->name` and local variable `name` are two different things. Don't confuse the readers

Answer (score 0):

```
bmw->name.length()
```

bmw is a pointer to your Stock object created on heap. So do access its member (like in your case name ) you have to use ->. After "bmw->name" would give you the string object. And that string object is not allocated using new means it's not on heap. So, do access it's member ( like length() in this case ) you have to use '.' .

Answer (score 0):

"use "->" for object that allocated in heap" is not accurate.
Simply when you want access to members of an object via pointer,you must use"->".
For other situation use ".".

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the native world, ruled by C++ !

In C++, you need to use `->` only when expression on left evaluates to a pointer of a `class`, `struct` or a `union`, otherwise use `.`. A function may also return a pointer to a object, and there you need to use `->` operator:

```
Stock* GetStockByIndex(int);
GetStockByIndex(0)->value;
```

Usage of `->` is not bound to `new`/heap, and usage of `.`is not bound to stack allocated object. It is just the context (*expression on left*).

In near future, you will also see that:

```
Stock s;
s->calculate();
```

How is that possible, you might wonder. It is because C++ allows `->` to be overloaded!

*Welcome!*